# Django Filter Provides Unexpected Results

Tags: python, django, django-models

Why does the following return no results:

```
>>> count = PlayerYear.objects.filter(team__id=3128).count()
>>> count # Output: 0
```

But this returns 32 (the number of players this year on the Admiral Farragut Academy Football team):

```
>>> count = PlayerYear.objects.filter(team__id=1).count()
>>> count # Output: 32
```

Given the following table (teams_team):

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|  id  | school_id |       admin_display                |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 3128 |     1     | Admiral Farragut Academy: Football |
```

And the following (abbreviated) models:

```
class PlayerYear(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    # snip
```

and

```
class Team(models.Model):
    legacy_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    # snip
```

and

```
class School(models.model):
    legacy_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    # snip
```

I do not understand why I get results when providing the `school_id` value, even though I specified `team__id` as the filter. How can I get results using the Team ID (3128)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your models it looks like you should be using `legacy_id` in your query rather than `id`:

```
count = PlayerYear.objects.filter(team__legacy_id=3128).count()
```

(Note: It appears that you have both a primary id field, and a legacy_id field in your database. You actually don't need to set ID fields manually in your models, since Django automatically does this for you. From the docs: `If you don't specify primary_key=True for any fields in your model, Django will automatically add an IntegerField to hold the primary key, so you don't need to set primary_key=True on any of your fields unless you want to override the default primary-key behavior.`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/

Comment: 3128 is your Team id or legacy_id?

Comment: `legacy_id` may or may not be relevant. There is no column in the table with that name, and performing the query you suggested returns no results. I rather think that it is a relic from previous iterations of the code. I included it in case I was wrong in that assumption.

Comment: @Felipe Cruz: 3128 is the Team `id`.

Comment: @George is there any way for you to see what fields are in the Team table in your db and post that here? It would be interesting to see which field holds the 3128 value.

Comment: Also, what happens when you run the following query `team = Team.objects.get(id=3128)` ?

Comment: @maz: I posted a sample from the table in the original question. The table is rather large, but if there are specific rows you would like to see, I can post additional details.

Comment: @maz: When I run `team = Team.objects.get(id=3128)` I receive one result: 'Admiral Farragut Academy: Football'.

Comment: Does this work: `team = Team.objects.get(id=3128)  count = PlayerYear.objects.filter(team=team).count()`

Comment: @maz: That runs but returns zero results.

Comment: @George if everything is set up correctly that last query should work (in fact your original query should work). The sample table you posted doesn't match your model. That indicates that there's some discrepancy between the model structure and the actual table structure. If you don't mind losing your data you may want to drop and rebuild the database. Otherwise you would have to manually make sure your tables match your models and are set up correctly to reflect ForeignKey, etc.

Comment: @maz: I think the discrepancy may be at the heart of the issue. I don't have the luxury of obliterating the existing data, but I may be able to massage it into place. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try if this works:

`>>> count = PlayerYear.objects.filter(team=Team.objects.get(3128)).count()`

Comment: That yields: _TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable_. Furthermore, even if a refinement of this approach works, I may not be able to utilize it. I am testing in the CLI, but must use a standard filter string because of the way the data is passed in the application itself.